# Calculate moving average of 90 days in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am new to bigquery and trying to calculate moving average over 90 days for a sample data.

The sample data looks like below :

```
+---------------+-------------+----------+--------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|   incident_id |  inc start  |  inc description| element_name|          uid          | is_repeated |
+---------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------|-----------------------+-------------+
| 1             | 1/5/2022    | server down     | vm-001      |   vm-001_server_down  |     No      |
| 2             | 1/5/2022    | server down     | vm-001      |   vm-001_server_down  |     No      |
| 3             | 2/5/2022    | firewall issue  | vm-002      |  vm-002_firewall_issue|     No      |
| 4             | 3/5/2022    | firewall issue  | vm-003      |  vm-003_firewall_issue|     No      |
| 5             | 1/6/2022    | server down     | vm-001      |  vm-001_server_down   |    Yes      |
| 6             | 1/6/2022    | server down     | vm-001      |  vm-001_server_down   |    Yes      |
| 7             | 2/6/2022    | server unreach  | vm-003      |  vm-003_server_unreach|     No      |
| 8             | 19/11/2022  | server down     | vm-001      |  vm-001_server_down   |     No      |
---------------+-------------+----------+------------+-------|-----------+------------+-------------+
```

if inc description and  uid occurs more than twice it should be represent "yes" in ISREPEATED column within 90 days.

What is the fastest way to acheive this using SQL ?

Answer (score 1):

Condisier below query:

1. aggregate incident days over 90 days for each **uid** first,
2. and then remove duplicate days and count unique days of incidents.

```sql
WITH incidents AS (
  SELECT *,
         ARRAY_AGG(start) OVER (
           PARTITION BY uid 
               ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(PARSE_DATE('%e/%m/%Y', start))
               RANGE BETWEEN 89 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
         ) AS inc_days
    FROM sample_table
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(inc_days),
       IF ((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT day) FROM UNNEST(inc_days) day) > 1, 'YES', 'NO') AS is_repeated
  FROM incidents
 ORDER BY id;
```

[image]